# IBM MQ v8 and Glassfish local setup port configuration issue

Tags: java, glassfish, ibm-mq, payara

Given the following local setup:

- IBM WebSphere MQ Advanced for Developers V8.0
- Payara 4.1.2.172

I'd like to connect to the local queue manager via JMS on other than the default port (1414).
In spite I added several properties to the connection factory to configure port 1415, it seems that the server is still trying to connect via port 1414, as Payara constantly throws `java.net.ConnectException`.

The relevant part of my domain.xml:

```xml
    <connector-connection-pool resource-adapter-name="wmq.jmsra" name="jms/testCP" connection-definition-name="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" transaction-support="XATransaction"></connector-connection-pool>
    <connector-resource pool-name="jms/testCP" jndi-name="jms/testCF">
      <property name="transportType" value="CLIENT"></property>
      <property name="port" value="1415"></property>
      <property name="channel" value="CHANNEL1"></property>
      <property name="hostName" value="localhost"></property>
      <property name="localAddress" value="localhost(1415)"></property>
      <property name="connectionNameList" value="localhost(1415)"></property>
      <property name="queuemanager" value="testQM"></property>
      <property name="username" value="mqm"></property>
    </connector-resource>
```

However the exception in `server.log` suggests that the resource adapter still wants to connect via port 1414:

```
    [2017-08-20T12:41:47.366+0200] [Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=63 _ThreadName=AutoDeployer] [timeMillis: 1503225707366] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
    java.lang.Exception
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:215)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainer.(MessageBeanContainer.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainerFactory.createContainer(MessageBeanContainerFactory.java:63)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:224)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:290)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:100)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:314)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:220)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:487)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoOperation.run(AutoOperation.java:164)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deploy(AutoDeployer.java:597)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deployAll(AutoDeployer.java:484)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:412)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:403)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployService$1.run(AutoDeployService.java:233)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
    Caused by: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011 An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail. See the linked exception for details of the failure.
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:174)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:135)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ConnectionHandler.allocateConnection(ConnectionHandler.java:393)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.acquireConnection(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:288)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.(MessageEndpointDeployment.java:228)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl.endpointActivation(ResourceAdapterImpl.java:531)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:207)
        ... 31 more
    Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager '' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.
    Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:489)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.(WMQConnection.java:413)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQXAConnection.(WMQXAConnection.java:67)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:188)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7814)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createProviderXAConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:98)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createXAConnectionInternal(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:347)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAConnectionFactory.createXAConnection(MQXAConnectionFactory.java:131)
        at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ConnectionHandler.allocateConnection(ConnectionHandler.java:268)
        ... 35 more
    Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
        ... 43 more
    Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9213: A communications error for 'TCP' occurred. [1=java.net.ConnectException[Connection refused (Connection refused)],3=connnectUsingLocalAddress,4=TCP,5=Socket.connect]],3=localhost(1414),5=RemoteTCPConnection.connnectUsingLocalAddress]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:2282)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1294)
        at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:376)
        at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:560)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.(WMQConnection.java:346)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9213: A communications error for 'TCP' occurred. [1=java.net.ConnectException[Connection refused (Connection refused)],3=connnectUsingLocalAddress,4=TCP,5=Socket.connect]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.connnectUsingLocalAddress(RemoteTCPConnection.java:838)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1277)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:863)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:409)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:305)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:146)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1730)
        ... 46 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection$5.run(RemoteTCPConnection.java:823)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection$5.run(RemoteTCPConnection.java:814)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.connnectUsingLocalAddress(RemoteTCPConnection.java:814)
        ... 52 more
    ]]
```

I'm out of ideas why the exception says: 
`JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager '' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.`

*Question 1*: Why is queue manager '' (empty)?

*Question 2*: Why is host name 'localhost(1414)'?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: We found a solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59945163/3623232

Answer (score 1):

In reviewing the IBM MQ v8 Knowledge Center page "[Installing and testing the resource adapter in GlassFish Server](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q121520_.htm)" it appears you have the wrong property name for the host name and queue manager.  Try the following config. Checkout the documentation link above to make sure you have installed the RA and the other steps.

```
<connector-connection-pool resource-adapter-name="wmq.jmsra" name="jms/testCP" connection-definition-name="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" transaction-support="XATransaction"></connector-connection-pool>
<connector-resource pool-name="jms/testCP" jndi-name="jms/testCF">
  <property name="transportType" value="CLIENT"></property>
  <property name="port" value="1415"></property>
  <property name="channel" value="CHANNEL1"></property>
  <property name="host" value="localhost"></property>
  <property name="queueManager" value="testQM"></property>
</connector-resource>
```

Comment: Tried with both the `host` and `hostName` properties. Same result (exception). Btw according to [Configuring the resource adapter for outbound communication](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031680_.htm) the property name is `hostName`.
I corrected `queueManager`, thanks for pointing out. However I guess the property names are handled case insensitive in MQ.
The issue keeps persisting.

Comment: Did you also remove localAddress and connectionNameList?

Comment: Did you try them together?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "together", sorry.

Comment: host without the other two properties.

Comment: You would use either connectionNameList or host, but not both and localAddress is meant to be the address and port the outbound connection binds to, in this case you are specifying the port the queue manager has a listener attached to, so you can't bind to it.  So you should not specify localAddress or connectionNameList and try just host.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the [article referenced by JoshMC](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q121520_.htm) is incorrect. Step 6.f should not form part of the "Connector Resource" (connection factory) configuration, but the "Connector Connection Pool" configuration, i.e. between 5.f and 5.g.

If you create a new connection pool using the Admin Console then it displays many properties that can be populated. The following are the important ones:

- channel
- port
- **hostName**
- queueManager
- transportType
- username

such that the domain.xml should contain the following:

```
<connector-connection-pool resource-adapter-name="wmq.jmsra" name="jms/testCP" connection-definition-name="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" transaction-support="XATransaction">
  <property name="channel" value="CHANNEL1"></property>
  <property name="port" value="1415"></property>
  <property name="hostName" value="localhost"></property>
  <property name="queueManager" value="testQM"></property>
  <property name="transportType" value="CLIENT"></property>
  <property name="username" value="mqm"></property>
</connector-connection-pool>
```

Answer (score 1):

We found that we used the wrong version of the `wmq.jmsra` adapter.
We were using `7.5.0.4-p750-004-140807`. With a newer Version `8.0.0.8-p800-008-171121` everything worked fine.