# Failed to allocate a JMS connection Payara and Websphere MQ

Tags: glassfish, ibm-mq, payara

[WebSphere MQ installation subdirectory]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vryhW.png)I installed an IBM resource adapter to a Payara (Glassfish) server using the instructions on the below page from the IBM website:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q121520_.htm

However when I try to test the Connector Connection Pool using the ping option I get the following error:
'Ping Connection Pool failed for jms/ivt/IVTCF-Connection-Pool. MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011 Please check the server.log for more details.'

I am running Payara Server 4.1.2.181 and trying to connect to IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer Version: 8.0.0.5. Below are the relevant connection details from the domain.xml file I am using:

```
<connector-connection-pool resource-adapter-name="wmq.jmsra" max-pool-size="250" ping="true" steady-pool-size="1" name="jms/ivt/IVTCF-Connection-Pool" connection-definition-name="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">
      <property name="transportType" value="CLIENT"></property>
      <property name="queueManager" value="QM"></property>
      <property name="channel" value="SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN"></property>
      <property name="port" value="1418"></property>
      <property name="hostName" value="localhost"></property>
    </connector-connection-pool>
    <connector-resource pool-name="jms/ivt/IVTCF-Connection-Pool" jndi-name="IVTCF"></connector-resource>
    <admin-object-resource res-adapter="wmq.jmsra" res-type="javax.jms.Queue" jndi-name="IVTQueue" class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy">
      <property name="baseQueueManagerName" value="QM"></property>
      <property name="name" value="IVTQueue"></property>
      <property name="CCSID" value="1208"></property>
      <property name="failIfQuiesce" value="true"></property>
      <property name="messageBodyStyle" value="UNSPECIFIED"></property>
      <property name="readAheadClosePolicy" value="ALL"></property>
      <property name="encoding" value="NATIVE"></property>
      <property name="priority" value="APP"></property>
      <property name="putAsyncAllowed" value="DESTINATION"></property>
      <property name="readAheadAllowed" value="DESTINATION"></property>
      <property name="persistence" value="APP"></property>
      <property name="targetClient" value="JMS"></property>
      <property name="expiry" value="APP"></property>
    </admin-object-resource>
```

Comment: `Please check the server.log for more details.` OK, any details in there? Your queuemanager is running on the same host as Payara, using port 1418?

Comment: Are you sure you followed that tutorial correctly? E.g. you have specified property `hostName` but in the linked tutorial I can only see `host`.

Comment: Yes I deliberately set the port to 1418 because there is another queue manager running on port 1414. And yes the property is supposed to be hostName instead of host.

Comment: The only thing logged in the server.log file is: [2019-11-18T12:47:26.599+0200] [Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=273 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(18)] [timeMillis: 1574074046599] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE.  endpoint = 'http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/ping-connection-pool.json'; attrs = '{id=jms%2Fivt%2FIVTCF-Connection-Pool}']]

Comment: What is in the error log file `AMQERR01.LOG` of the Queue Manager?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781906/ibm-mq-v8-and-glassfish-local-setup-port-configuration-issue It is mentioned that there might be an error in the documentation. Did you try specifiying the `username`?

Comment: @Daniel Steinmann There is no AMQERR01.LOG file. There isn't even a qmname folder under the WebSphere MQ installation path.

Comment: @ChristophJohn I checked that link before posting this question and tried all the suggestions there but with no luck.

Comment: One last thing: could you try to use names without slashes? Just a gut feeling but the error message you posted above formats the connection pool url-encoded. `id=jms%2Fivt%2FIVTCF-Connection-Pool` Maybe Payara does something wrong there? Or maybe this is expected and it is just encoded before putting it to the log file. Who knows...

Comment: IIRC there was a restriction for the names. In JNDI the slash was allowed but not for the internal name. IIRC at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="queueManager" value="QM"></property>
<property name="channel" value="SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN"></property>
<property name="port" value="1418"></property>
<property name="hostName" value="localhost"></property>
```

Do you have a local queue called 'QM'?  You are using 'localhost', so is it running on your local PC?  And did you configure the MQ listener to use port # 1418?

Finally, do not use the "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN".  Create a channel for your own use.  i.e. 'TEST.CHL'.  Also, you could be blocked from using the SYSTEM.* channel by a CHLAUTH rule.

Comment: I have a queueManager called QM and I am running everything locally on my PC. I even tried changing the hostName from 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1'. I am using that specific channel based on the instructions IBM webpage. Will check the CHLAUTH rule.

Comment: @user5822870: Since you have a local queue manager, there *must* be the queue manager error file. Since you are talking about PC, I assume it is Windows, so please look in `C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QM\errors\AMQERR01.LOG`.

Comment: @DanielSteinmann I am attempting to add the image to show the subdirectories in the WebSphere MQ subfolder but am unable to in the comment. It does not contain the qmgrs subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

As @Roger had highlighted, the issue in my case was that the channel was blocked by the CHLAUTH rule. I fixed the issue by disabling authorisation on the channel using the below commands on the IBM Integration Console:

alter QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)
alter AUTHINFO(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS) AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS) CHCKCLNT(none) 
REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)

Comment: Disabling security is not a recommended practice, you could have as Roger recommended defined a new channel to use instead of the SYSTEM channel (which is also not recommended), you would then not need to disable CHLAUTH and pass a username and password to authenticate so that you would not need to disable CONNAUTH.